# move_uploaded_file is giving a error

Tags: php

**this is my form**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="myform"> 
<table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="369" colspan="3">Admin's Area </td>
    <td width="121"><?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">sponseres list </td>
    <td><a href="admin.php#sponserForm">+Add new Sponser</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $sponsere_list; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"> <a name="sponserForm" id="sponserForm"></a> Add New Sponser Form</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Sponser name</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="spname" id="spname" tabindex="1" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Image</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Add this</td>
    <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="sumit" id="sumit" value="Submit" tabindex="3" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**and this is the php code to retrive it**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['spname'])){
    $spname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['spname']);
    $user_query = "INSERT INTO `sponsers` (`spname`)
                                    VALUES ('{$spname}')
                                    ";
    $sql=mysql_query($user_query)or die (mysql_error());
    $spic= mysql_insert_id();
    $newname="$spic.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"../sponsers/$newname")or die (mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

**when i try to upload a image it gives me this warning message
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in J:\xampp\htdocs\srimag\admin\test.php on line 3**

**so i tried to echo the fileToUpload value by using $_POST['fileToUpload'] it show the values without errors so can't figure out the error.**

**so please help me on this :-(**
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is you are missing the appropriate `enctype` attribute on your form

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Make sure you read this section of the manual carefully - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Your issue is mentioned on the [first page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> **Note:**
>
> Be sure your file upload form has attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` otherwise the file upload will not work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as best answer if you think so @user1367975 :)

Answer (score 2):

You need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form to upload images, also it would be a good idea to check if user even uploads an image and specificity naming a file `.jpg` will not work, images will be treated as corrupt when outputting if ther not jpegs, not to mention people uploading php files.

You also need to make some other checks on validity, upload security is not something that should be overlooked, else you have one of thos awful phone home / botnet malware scripts injecting code into all your scripts:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['spname'])){
    $spname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['spname']);
    $user_query = "INSERT INTO `sponsers` (`spname`)
                                    VALUES ('{$spname}')";
    $sql=mysql_query($user_query)or die (mysql_error());
    $spic= mysql_insert_id();



    if(isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] ==0){
        $name    = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name']);
        $ext     = end(explode('.', $name));
        $newname = $spic.".".$ext;
        $info    = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name']);

        $allowed = array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif');
        if($info[0]>0 && $info[1] > 0 && in_array($info['mime'],$allowed)){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'], "../sponsers/$newname");
            //done upload
        }else{
            //Not allowed, perhap notify user
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

include this in form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your form

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```